# Better way to convert int to string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring

I am wondering if there is a better way to convert int to string
Basically I have a counter and a dictionary

```
//
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
int cnt = 0;
//
// insert an object
//
id object = [[[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", cnt++];
[dict setObject:object forKey:key];
```

The thing is converting int to string takes more time than I expected.
So is there a better way to get around this?

Comment: "converting int to string takes more time than I expected" Perhaps your expectations were too low. How do you know they were correct?

Comment: i would like to know , how you can say "converting int to string takes more time than I expected" . means how you determine this even?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I think that op ask about low-level str functions, apple says about stringWithFormat as slow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose this is mildly faster:

```
NSString* yourString = [@(yourInteger) stringValue];
```

And this

```
[dict setObject:yourObj forKey:[@(yourInt) stringValue]];
```

Does look better than:

```
[dict setObject:yourObj forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",yourInt]];
```

But we're really splitting hairs here from both speed and style points of view.

Comment: i would really like to know ,"do you thing stringValue is much faster the stringWithFormat" ?

Comment: no , you answered it here , that is what OP is looking for . a faster method to covert a string from int.

Comment: i think OP has assumed that stringValue is much faster then stringWithFormat.

Comment: I thought he was looking purely for style...  I believe this is a little faster as well though, we're really really splitting hairs on both the style and speed discussions.  It is nominal at best.  Something for the OP to consider at least.  Instead of just getting the question downvoted to oblivion :)

Answer (score 1):

[Interesting link about nsfoundation](https://github.com/danielamitay/iOS-App-Performance-Cheatsheet/blob/master/Foundation.md#nsstring)

Quote:

> NSString creation is not particularly expensive, but when used in a
>   tight loop (as dictionary keys, for example), +[NSString
>   stringWithFormat:] performance can be improved dramatically by being
>   replaced with asprintf or similar functions in C.

and code example:

```
NSString *firstName = @"Daniel";
NSString *lastName = @"Amitay";
char *buffer;
asprintf(&buffer, "Full name: %s %s", [firstName UTF8String], [lastName UTF8String]);
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
free(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you explicity need it as a string? Or maybe just use literals(note that it will be NSNumber in this case):

```
[dict setObject:object forKey:@(cnt++)];
```

Comment: What happens if he's looking for @"3" after inserting @(3)...  Nothing good.

Comment: As I said if he do not need it as a string later he can use this. Me personally don't like converting int/floats to NSString just to fulfill NSDictionary object requirement, NSNumber is the perfect solution for this. However if you really truly need int to NSString conversion above won't work.

Comment: Fair point, but your assuming this is his only usecase for wanting to convert ints to strings.  It is more likely just a poorly scripted example to demo his question.